# Offer option to disable audio autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I'm a radio presenter and have an mp3 stream of my broadcasts set up to autoplay on my website **(I know, I know, just humour me)**. Using the HTML5 audio tag, I want the audio to autoplay the first time someone visits my site.

However, I want them to be able to check a checkbox with the result that the audio never autoplays for them again unless they uncheck the checkbox.

This checkbox should appear just under the audio player and change the autoplay tag from "true" to "false".

I've seen plugins that will stop autoplay, but can't find any code online to offer the option myself, which just goes to show how many people use autoplay indiscriminately. I would never dream of using it without offering a disable option.

Following some quick research I have put together the following code, but as I am a n00b coder I can't make it work. Where am I going wrong and what is the most elegant solution?

```js
function check(that){
 if(that.value === "disable-autoplay"){
        if((this).is(':checked')){
            autoplay="no"('checked');
  }
 }else {
   autoplay="autoplay"('unchecked');
    }
}
```

```html
<audio controls autoplay="true"><source src="stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<input type="checkbox" name="disable-autoplay" value="disable-autoplay" onchange="check(this)" />
```

Comment: What do mean by "disabling autoplay"? User can't do it before first visit of your page.The page is loaded first, then your player starts playing or waits for user action depending on autload prop, afterwards user can click your checbox

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

> autoplay:
>   A Boolean attribute; if specified (even if the value is "false"!), the audio will automatically begin playback as soon as it can do so, without waiting for the entire audio file to finish downloading

First thing is don't assign any autoplay at all in your HTML

```
 <audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Create the checkbox with some selector like id  also don't assign event handler in the attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" name="disableAutoplay" id="disableAutoplay" />
```

Now i suppose you want the preference to persist entire site so even if user refreshes /navigates around your site, his preference should stay, for that use cookies or browser storage.
 I think using local storage would be better due to its simplicity

```
localStorage.setItem('disableAP','yes');            //saving
disableAutoplay = localStorage.getItem('disableAP');//retriing
```

see how simple it is.

Now whenever page loads just check user pref. from above variable in storage and accordingly enable/disable `autoplay` property of the audio and check/uncheck the checkbox

now comes the most important part : the `load()` method

> The load() method is used to update the audio/video element after changing the source or other settings.

load() function is the heart of this code it **refreshes your audio element with newly assigned config.** but **without actually refreshing the page** or editing HTML physically so in essence it gives you the effect of dynamic markup.

see how load() is being used below in check() function

```
var chkAutoPlay = document.getElementById('disableAutoplay');
var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');

function check(that){
    if (that.checked)             //checkbox is checked
    {
        myAudio.autoplay=false;
        localStorage.setItem('disableAP','yes');

    } else {                      //checkbox is not checked                   
        myAudio.autoplay=true;
        localStorage.setItem('disableAP','no');
        myAudio.load();
    }
}
```

finally assign event handler for checkbox

```
document.getElementById('disableAutoplay').onchange=check;
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sanddune/oz0nhv2k/